# Test database is empty while querying inside a view

Tags: python, django, database

I have a scenario where I'm conditionally checking a visitor's registration form data (via subclass of `UserCreationForm`).

If there are no existing Users with the username that the visitor provides, a new `User` is created. Otherwise, the conditionals are checked and the visitor receives a flash message (ie. `f"Username {username} exists. Choose another username."`

Upon creating a `TestCase`, I have created an existing `User` with the usage of `User.objects.create_user()`. When testing the view, the QuerySet is empty when performing the query `User.objects.get()`. As a result `User.DoesNotExist` is raised, which is not the desired outcome. Rather the desired outcome is to branch into the `else` clause instead.

Why would the test database be empty of `User` instances while testing the view when it was populated in `setUpTestData`?

**test_views.py**

```
class TestCreateNewChef_Case2(TestCase):

    def setUpTestData(cls):
        User.objects.create_user(
            username='masterchef',
            password='password',

        )
        cls.user_signup_data = {
            'username': 'masterchef',
            'password1': 'secret',
            'password2': 'secret'
        }

        print(User.objects.all()) # <QuerySet [<User: masterchef>]>

    def test_new_chef_sign_up_username_taken(self):
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse("chef:register"), 
            self.user_signup_data,
            follow=True

        )
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse("chef:register"))
        self.assertTemplateUsed('chef/register_chef.html')
        self.assertContains(
            response,
            "<p>Username masterchef exists. Choose another username.</p>",
            html=True
        )
```

**views.py**

```
def register_chef(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_user_form = ChefRegisterationForm(request.POST)
        if new_user_form.is_valid():
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(
                    username=new_user_form.cleaned_data['username']
                )
                stored_password = check_password(
                    new_user_form.cleaned_data['check_password'], 
                    user.password
                )
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                # if no Users exist with the username, create a new user
            else:
                # conditionally check existing users with the submitted username
```

```
(Pdb) User.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>
(Pdb) n
>(17)register_chef()
-> user = User.objects.get(
(Pdb) n
> (18)register_chef()
-> username=new_user_form.cleaned_data['username']
(Pdb) n
django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`setUpTestData`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData) with `classmethod` decorator:

```
@classmethod
def setUpTestData(cls):
    User.objects.create_user(
        username='masterchef',
        password='password',

    )
    cls.user_signup_data = {
        'username': 'masterchef',
        'password1': 'secret',
        'password2': 'secret'
    }
```